# Multiple paired t-tests in R

Tags: r, t-test

This seems like it should be very simple but I just can't wrap my mind around it. Other questions/examples on here have dozens of variables, and I only have two, so I've been trying to figure out how to adapt them to my data but to no avail.

```
df <- data.frame(month = month.abb, amount.x = runif(12), amount.y = runif(12))
```

I want to run 12 t-tests, one for each month. The ideal output would be 12 p-values, or at the very least a list of 12 so I can see the results of each test. I've tried various forms of `map()` and it keeps either throwing errors or just comparing each amount variable to itself instead of comparing each pair.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: have you tried the solutions in this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609694/perform-multiple-paired-t-tests-based-on-groups-categories

Comment: You can't run 12 t-tests. You have two observations in each month (one in each column). It doesn't make sense to try to do a t-test of a single value against a single value. Or am I misunderstanding what you are asking?

Comment: @StupidWolf that solution worked! Now I feel very silly that my search terms didn't bring that one up and only gave me more complicated examples. Thank you!

Comment: note Allan Cameron's comment. Make sure one have more than 1 observation per group for each month