How do I run a t-test on each entry of my data frame?
I have a data set that contains genes and some information about their expression that looks like this:
dput(head(diffexpr))
structure(list(...1 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6), Gene = c("ML087114a", 
"ML20265a", "ML463533a", "ML085213a", "ML01433a", "ML01248a"), 
    `aboral-1` = c(2.822658847, 2.822658847, 8.467976541, 47.04431412, 
    212.6402998, 9.408862823), `aboral-2` = c(7.984581931, 13.30763655, 
    20.40504271, 90.49192855, 333.5780896, 4.435878851), `aboral-3` = c(1.712278262, 
    6.849113047, 9.41753044, 42.80695655, 415.2274785, 7.705252178
    ), `aboral-4` = c(0.983752211, 18.69129201, 12.78877874, 
    52.13886718, 471.2173091, 13.77253095), `oral-1` = c(17974.26123, 
    1740.952875, 547.3137791, 1902.305011, 14912.23774, 443.7183737
    ), `oral-2` = c(20852.10726, 1234.05124, 515.7229063, 2200.489964, 
    12982.99913, 430.1302391), `oral-3` = c(42894.61215, 2117.228589, 
    692.7337779, 3194.136909, 22573.60827, 473.205468), `oral-4` = c(39617.46967, 
    1759.240408, 558.5421067, 2592.036723, 26045.23093, 367.9019864
    )), row.names = c(NA, -6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))

aboral <- c(diffexpr[,3,4,5,6])
oral <- c(diffexpr[,7,8,9,10])
 

I am wanting to run a t-test on all of the aboral and oral data for each entry. I have already combined each aboral column into one variable and all oral columns into another, as shown above.
I have already tried using lapply(), but something about how I am specifying which variables the test need to be run on is preventing execution. I keep getting the error that the t.test() command as I wrote it is not a function. The errors looked like this:
> lapply(diffexpr,t.test(aboral,oral,conf.level = 0.95))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  't.test(aboral, oral, conf.level = 0.95)' is not a function, character or symbol
> lapply(diffexpr,t.test(aboral,oral))
Error in match.fun(FUN) : 
  't.test(aboral, oral)' is not a function, character or symbol
> lapply(diffexpr,t.test())
Error in t.test.default() : argument "x" is missing, with no default

I have not yet learned how to do for loops in R, but have a good idea since I have a little experience in Python.  I think I still have the same issue in formatting/selection of variables. I wrote it out as shown below, but the output is the same as if I had run this particular test outside of the loop.
for (i in diffexpr[,1]){
+     print(t.test(aboral,oral,conf.level = 0.95))}

Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  aboral and oral
t = -0.532, df = 33091, p-value = 0.5947
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -59.08125  33.85595
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 493.1165  505.7292 

> t.test(aboral,oral,conf.level = 0.95)

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  aboral and oral
t = -0.532, df = 33091, p-value = 0.5947
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -59.08125  33.85595
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
 493.1165  505.7292 

#trying to incorporate the row into the command directly
> print(for (x in diffexpr[,1]){t.test(c(diffexpr[x,3,4,5,6]),c(diffexpr[x,7,8,9,10]),conf.level = 0.95)})
NULL

If anyone knows how I can run a t-test on the "aboral" and "oral" variables for each entry I would greatly appreciate it. There are over 16,000 entries so automation would be good too. Base R commands would be preferred. Thank you!

This question appears to be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42609694/perform-multiple-paired-t-tests-based-on-groups-categories/42610257, but if your question is different in some way, or if the answers fail to solve your problem, please leave a comment explaining the difference and it can be reopened.

so i need to use the two variables that combine 4 of the columns for comparison. can you show me how i would do that using the method in the question i duplicated? i think i can use it, but am not sure how to apply it for my needs. these variables arent apart of the data frame.

and i believe if i add the aboral/oral variables to the data frame, i will get an error because those to columns would be longer than the list of genes

I would use: library(tidyverse); library(rstatix); diffexpr %>% select(-...1) %>% pivot_longer(-Gene) %>% mutate(group = str_remove(name, "-.")) %>% group_by(Gene) %>% t_test(value ~ group) . This works with your example dataset, but you will need to install the rstatix package (install.packages("rstatix")) and, depending on the number of genes you are analysing, you will need to adjust your p-values for multiple comparisons (e.g. per https://doi.org/10.22074%2Fcellj.2019.5992). Good luck @axr!

I need the commands to use base R. do you have a solution that is able to utilize that?

With base R, perhaps you could use sapply(1:nrow(diffexpr), \(x) t.test(as.numeric(as.character(unlist(diffexpr[x,c(3:6)]), as.numeric(as.character(unlist(diffexpr[x,c(7:10)]))))))$p.value)? Does that work with your actual data?

no, some of the the entries are reporting NaN. it appears to be for ones who have 0 as the value for all of the aboral columns, which are 3:6. it does not happen for any entries that have all 0s in columns 7:10. do you know why that might be happening, and is it expected?

i will later need to apply corrections to the p values, specifically FDR and Bonferroni. do you think this formatting will allow me to do that later on?

Bonferroni correction is straightforward (α / n) and you can apply this using this same formatting, but I'm not sure how you would apply FDR so I can't advise you sorry. Just FYI, stackoverflow is for programming and software development questions; I highly recommend asking statistics questions at https://stats.stackexchange.com/ (you have a much better chance of getting an answer). Good luck!
